# Upload to S3 using Gzip in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to upload a large file ( ~10GB ) to Amazon S3. Could anyone please help me with how to use GZip outputsteam for it ?
I've been through some documentations but got confused about Byte Streams, Gzip streams. They must be used together ? Can anyone help me with this piece of code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, you should be more specific of what approach you're using and what code.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this,

[Is it possible to gzip and upload this string to Amazon S3 without ever being written to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580659/is-it-possible-to-gzip-and-upload-this-string-to-amazon-s3-without-ever-being-wr)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZipOuputStream gzipOut = new GZipOutputStream(byteOut);
// write your stuff
byte[] bites = byteOut.toByteArray();
//write the bites to the amazon stream
```

Since its a large file you might want to have a look at multi part upload

Comment: I saw this. But didnt get the part why we need 2 output streams. Say my file is "Text.txt". How will the above code change ?

Answer (score 1):

This question could have been more specific and there are several ways to achieve this. One approach might look like the below.

The example depends on the `commons-io` and `commons-compress` libraries, and uses classes from the `java.nio.file` package.

```java
public static void compressAndUpload(AmazonS3 s3, InputStream in)
    throws IOException
{
    // Create temp file
    Path tmpPath = Files.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix");

    // Create and write to gzip compressor stream
    OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(tmpPath);
    GzipCompressorOutputStream gzOut = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(out);
    IOUtils.copy(in, gzOut);

    // Read content from temp file
    InputStream fileIn = Files.newInputStream(tmpPath);
    long size = Files.size(tmpPath);
    
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentType("application/x-gzip");
    metadata.setContentLength(size);

    // Upload file to S3
    s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucket", "key", fileIn, metadata));
}
```

Buffering, error handling and closing of streams are omitted for brevity.